# xmltodict: Not fetching correct nested elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, xmltodict

So I have an XML like that:

```
<main>
   <site>Amazon</site>
   <url>..</url>
    <books>
    <book>
        <id>1</id>
        <author>Jhon</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <id>2</id>
        <author>Jhon</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <id>3</id>
        <author>Jhon</author>
    </book>
    </books>
</main>
```

I am accessing it as:

```
document = xmltodict.parse(xml)
books = document['books]['book'] #returns 3
for book in books:
   pass
```

But if XML is like:

```
<books>
 <book>
    <id>3</id>
    <author>Jhon</author>
 </book>
</books>
```

then instead of **1** it returns **2** that is child of `<books>`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with `xmltodict`, which was discussed here:

- [xml containing 1 child](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/14)

The workaround to this behavior would be to use a `force_list` option (available in the master branch at the moment):

```
xmltodict.parse(data, force_list={'books': 'book'})
```

Comment: hmm interesting. It screwed up everything else: `books = document['books]['book']` not working anymore; gives error `list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @Volatil3 yeah, now it always is a list: `[book['author'] for book in document['books']]`..but I actually find it more logical..

Comment: I should have put entire XML. I just updated the Qs, there are not iterative elements as well and from what I am seeing, it seems it ruined the entire format

Comment: https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/14#issuecomment-143434259 should work for me but it's now call `force_list` an invalid keyword

Comment: OK I install latest by doing `sudo pip install git+https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict.git@master
` and it worked like charm

Comment: @Volatil3 okay, had to update accordingly, thanks for sharing.